# Are there any issues using a lambda expression in a foreach loop?

Tags: c#

I wrote a quick-n-dirty C# console application to search log files for string in another file. In one scenario, I passed in three files to search and one input file. The program loads all the values from the input file into memory as a list of objects. One of the properties of the objects is a boolean to mark the item as found.

Because I am expecting each value in the input file to be found only once, I update the object's property to true and then break out of the loop that is walking through each line of the log files. When the break is in place, the application says that 18 items were not matched. When the break is commented out, all input values are found. There are no duplicate values in the input file. Is it possible that my lambda expression not behaving as I thought?

```
while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    foreach (var needle in needles.Where(d => d.Found == false))
    {
        if (line.Contains(needle.SearchValue))
        {
            needle.Found = true;
            //break; //works without break, misses some with break
        }
    }
}
```

Sample of supposedly missing rows:

```
Completed Document 48166115
Completed Document 48166120
Completed Document 48371705
Completed Document 48371710
Completed Document 48371720
```

Sample of log that contains some of these values:

```
06/20/13 20:53:22 - Completed Document 48132000, 2 pages
06/20/13 20:53:23 - Completed Document 48166115, 2 pages
06/20/13 20:53:23 - Completed Document 48166116, 2 pages
06/20/13 20:53:23 - Completed Document 48166117, 2 pages
06/20/13 20:53:23 - Completed Document 48166118, 2 pages
06/20/13 20:53:24 - Completed Document 48166119, 2 pages
06/20/13 20:53:24 - Completed Document 48166120, 2 pages
06/20/13 20:53:24 - Completed Document 48166121, 2 pages
```

Comment: `break` is an explicit instruction to stop the loop that searches for the needles. It's not surprising that it leaves some needles unaccounted for.

Comment: I don't see how, though. I'm looping over the search values for each and every line in the file I am checking. When a match is found, I'm merely marking the item as found and then not wasting time checking the rest of the list.

Comment: Because some of your needles are on the same line.  So when you find a needle on a line and break and go to the next line, you've now left needles unaccounted for.

Comment: Your code **should** work fine with `break` assuming each line can only contain a single needle value. I would expect if it isn't working correctly then you have multiple needle values per line. Am I right?

Comment: I manually verified that the missing values appear once in the input file and once in the log file and on separate lines.

Comment: The files seem to all check out, so I'm going to add some code and see if my method for loading the values into a list of objects is somehow creating dups. I'm using a FileStream with a BufferedStream and a StreamReader.

Comment: I added code to check for dups while loading the list and no dups were detected.

Comment: The missed ones, are they same each time?  Can you provide an example of said missed line, and the line above it?

Comment: Yes, they are the same values each time. I added .ToList() to my foreach and added the break back and the behavior did not change. The code still says there are 18 missing. Puzzling!

Comment: At this point I would recommend you build a minimal application that reproduces the issue with a sample log file so that someone can take a look at it.

Comment: I running the app in debug mode and using a conditional break (first time I've needed that!). I think the issue is going to be caused by one string containing another string, causing an unexpected match. Removing the break probably fixes the issues by allowing two items to match to the same string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In an attempt to fix the issue, I added another parameter to the program to allow a suffix to be added to the search values in the input file. So, the line.Contains method argument basically included prefix +  + suffix.

In the logs there was a comma after the document number, so I passed that as the suffix. The program indicated that 22 items were not found. I was really confused then until I started checking the missing values. They really were missing!

So, what happened was this:

Without the break, the shorter number was matching a larger one incorrectly and the larger one was matching correctly. (No missing values)

With the break, the shorter number was matching a larger one in error and the larger one was getting skipped. The skipped values were actually present, which confused me.

With the break and the suffix, the smaller missing values were correctly being logged as missing and the larger values were being found. So, the scanner is now faster and more accurate then before.

Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

You might have already done this, but just to rule out something happening you aren't aware of, you could put a control variable increment
inside of your flag. Check at the end your numbers match what you are expecting. How many flags should be changed to true? How many were actually hit?

```
if (line.Contains(needle.SearchValue))
    {
        needle.Found = true;  
        controlVariable++;
    }
```

Comment: I like the idea (though not an answer) to help rule out if your lines are malformed or word wrap is disguising two lines as one from you.

Comment: I actually added the count as a property of the object and then, at the end, I wrote out duplicate matches found, but none were found.

Answer (score 0):

Your break is breaking out of the whole foreach loop, so the first of the needles which were previously !Found would then stop the others being checked for.

This means that if multiple needles succeeded on one line, then only the first would be marked, the rest would be missed. Given that you're only expecting one success this would mean that they'd never succeed.

Comment: There should only be one match per line in the log file I am checking

Comment: You say here that you only expect one match, but in your problem description you state that your problem is that "18 items were not matched". Are you expecting one or 18 matches?

Comment: The input files contains 300,000 values on their own lines. The list contains one object per line in the input file. I'm expecting each value to be found in the log file just once. So, I'm expecting 300,000 matches.

Comment: The fact that some expected matches are being missed when the break is in place and that when missing the break they are found implies that the break is at fault. Unless there's more to the code than is in this snippet, the obvious flaw is multiple hits per line - not the use of lambda. An alternative explanation could be partial matches - you use .Contains rather than .Equals, after all.

Comment: I'm using contains because the full line in the log has a timestamp and other formatting. Instead of trying to regex the pattern, I'm just looking if the string is anywhere in the line.

Answer (score 0):

the break is exiting the foreach loop so once you find the first match all subsequent needles will remain unsearched.

You must have duplicates if taking the break out results in all items being matched.

Comment: That is my intention. I don't want to check the other values in the list when a match is found.

Comment: what is the issue then?  I don't understand what the problem is.

Comment: If it works when you take the BREAK out then doesn't that tell you that you infact do have duplicates?

Comment: instead of a list of needles, use a dictionary to ensure you've not added any dups.

Comment: I agree that duplicates would cause the issue, but the missing values get written to a file. I've manually checked them and they are present in the log file only once and present in the input file only once.